# Setting custom (Powerline) fonts in the default OSX Terminal app

Tags: terminal.app, iterm2, iterm, powerline-networking, fontconfig

I was able to set a custom font in Iterm 2 by setting the Non-ASCII option in Iterm's setting.

I was not able to find a similar option in the default Mac OS Terminal. How can I do this for Mac OS Terminal?

[image]

Comment: What does the network wiring have to do with fonts?

Answer (score 0):

In **Preferences > Settings > Text** you can change the font.

[image]

Comment: I set it there - and I still get the weird symbols. http://i.imgur.com/dZ4HS2Q.png

Comment: What are those symbols supposed to be?

Comment: in the original question, compare two screens. For example, the symbol on the right side of '1:1' is incorrectly rendered in the default OSX Terminal (the right screen).

Comment: OK, now I see the difference, but I can't figure out what the symbol in the left screen is. I suspect this doesn't have anything to do with fonts, but is because Terminal doesn't UTF-8 encoding. You might have better luck posting in the Apple discussion forum or apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Actually, it looks like Terminal does support UTF-8, maybe you're using a different encoding. Check the Character Encoding setting in Preferences>Settings>Advanced.

Comment: tried that...does not seem to be changing anything, unfortunately. Thank you, though